# CS50w - Project 1 - 404 page shown instead of search page

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, cs50

I try to solve cs50w project 1. But I faced an error in the project.

This is the `layout.html` file. I have a form action: go to search, and the name is q
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj47M.png)

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:title>/", views.title, name="title"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search"),
]
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        entry_search = request.POST['q']
        html_content = markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(entry_search))
        if html_content is not None:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/title.html", {
                "content": html_content,
                "title": entry_search,
            })
```

When I start my project and type something in the search bar, it sends me to the error.html page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn3Xe.png)
But it needs to take me to the title.html page.

Can you help me with this problem?

I need to face with title.html page, but it redirects to error.html

Comment: "search" is a fine `string`, that's why `<str:title>` catches your request first. Change pattern order. And please don't post code as pictures.

Comment: Also your `search` view does not return anything for alternative scenarios - where `if`s do not result in `true`. So it will not work in many scenarios.